# I Want to display input file name not full path

Tags: javascript, input

Here what I am getting is the full path of the input file but I need only the name of the selected file.

```js
function change() {
  let fnVal = document.getElementById('fn').value;
  document.getElementById('file-name').innerHTML = fnVal;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="file" name="" id="fn" onchange="change();">
  <span id="file-name">File Name</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You can rely on a filename not having a '/' or '\' in the title to find the file name. Figure out what folder separator the system is using, and do a `.split()` on that character, and get the last element in the array

Comment: IE with file protocol? Just split by `/`, and take the last part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A escaped backslash make a backslash in a string '\\'

So you will have to use `.split("\\")` to get the file name.

Try this:

```js
function change() {
  let fnVal = document.getElementById('fn').value.split("\\");;
  document.getElementById('file-name').innerHTML = fnVal[fnVal.length - 1];
}
```

```html
  <div><input type="file" name="" id="fn" onchange="change();"><span id="file-name">File Name</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that you store full path name in fnVal like this;

`let fnVal = 'path1/path2/path3/picture.jpg';`

You can extract the only file name by splitting the path with this

`let fileName = fnVal.split('/')[fnVal.split('/').length - 1]`

Comment: you can use `.pop()` instead of re-splitting the path again to get the last element